# Get the ID of the list row of the item your getting

Tags: list, sharepoint-addin

### Title  | Priority  | Status

title1 | priority1 | status1

This is what my list looks like, If I get the "status1" from Status, how do i get the ID of the items row?

what I want to do is having an on-click(onselected) on the status item I'm getting from the list, and through the ID get the value of Title1 on the same row. this must be possible? so far i've tried the following code:

```
function RetrieveListItems() {
var query = new SP.CamlQuery();

query.set_viewXml("<View>" +
"<Query>" +
"<Where>" +
//"<And>" +
"<Eq><FieldRef Name='Status'/><Value Type='Text'>Skapad</Value></Eq>" +
//"<Eq><FieldRef Name='Assigned_x0020_to'/><Value Type='Lookup'>"+ theuser +"</Value></Eq>" +
//"</And>" +
"</Where>" +
"</Query>" +
"</View>");

listItems = list.getItems(query);

context.load(listItems, 'Include(Status, ID)');

context.executeQueryAsync(OnSuccess2, OnFail)
}
function OnSuccess2() {
var OnGoing = document.getElementById('OnGoing');

OnGoing.options.length = 0;

var listEnumerator = listItems.getEnumerator();

while (listEnumerator.moveNext()) {

    var currentItem = listEnumerator.get_current();

    OnGoing.options[OnGoing.options.length] = new     Option(currentItem.get_item("Status"), currentItem.get_item("ID"));
    //var id = $(this).find('option:selected').attr('id');
}

}
function doSomething() {
var id = $(this).find('option:selected').attr('ID');
var query = new SP.CamlQuery();

query.set_viewXml("<View>" +
"<Query>" +
"<Where>" +
"<And>" +
"<Eq><FieldRef Name='Title'/><Value Type='Text'></Value></Eq>" +
"<Eq><FieldRef Name='ID' LookUpId='TRUE'/><Value Type='Counter'>" + id + "</Value></Eq>" +
"</And>" +
"</Where>" +
"</Query>" +
"</View>");

listItems1 = list.getItems(query);

context.load(listItems1);

context.executeQueryAsync(OnSuccessdoSomething, OnFail)
}
function OnSuccessdoSomething() {
var ListEnumerator = listItems.getEnumerator();
while (ListEnumerator.moveNext()) {
    var currentItem = ListEnumerator.get_current();
    var Description = currentItem.get_item('Title');
}
$("#divDescription").html(listItems1);
```

Comment: Please post code you have tried so far.

Comment: Does Title link to item? If so the url may contain the item id.

Comment: @AmalHashim I've posted the code I've tried so far.

Comment: @wjervis it does not link to the item, it's a "description" pretty much, I'm trying to get the description columns value through the status item of the same row.

Comment: Are you trying on Select change get the Title value?

Comment: Just to clarify, you have an html table that contains three columns: Title, Priority and Status.  When the user clicks on the Status column, you want to get the value in the Title column for that row?

Comment: @wjervis I do not have a html table, i get the Status from my sharepoint list, which has Title,Priority,Status and put it in a "select:option"

Comment: Which row are you referring to in your comment to Keerthi's answer? I think some more background information is required on what you are attempting.

Comment: @wjervis and when i select one of the options(status) i want to get the title(in the sharepoint list) of the same row as that selected status, so i can put it next to my select:option"dropdown" as a description for that item

Comment: @wjervis the row i am referring to is the sharepoint list row, I'm trying to get the Status from the sharepoint list, and then getting the Title from the sharepoint list, by select change on my dropdown also known as = <select id="OnGoing">

Comment: @AmalHashim yes, i'm trying to get the Title value from my sharepoint list from the same row as the Status which is selected

Answer (score 0):

You can get he ID by:

```
var ID = currentItem.get_id();
```

Comment: does this get me the ID of the items "row" or does this give me the ID of the actual item? I want to get the ID of the row so i can get Title from the same row as the selected Status.

Comment: It gives the ID of the item from which you can get the Title also.

Answer (score 0):

I believe fixing below function can get you `title`

```
function OnSuccessdoSomething() {
    var ListEnumerator = listItems.getEnumerator();
    while (ListEnumerator.moveNext()) {
        var currentItem = ListEnumerator.get_current();
        var Description = currentItem.get_item('Title');

        $("#divDescription").html(Description);
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: I get the following error: The Property or field has not been initialized. It has not been requested or the request has not been executed. It may need to be explicitly requested.

Comment: Thank you for taking your time to help me by the way, I really appreciate it.

Comment: Change this line `context.load(listItems, 'Include(Status, ID)');` to `context.load(listItems, 'Include(Title,Status, Id)');`